# Java 7 keytool Elliptic Curve Encryption

Tags: java, encryption, keytool, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to create a keystore using keytool with a keyalg ECC.

This should be possible according to [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html#jdk7changes).
I quote:

> Area: Tools
>
> Synopsis: The `keytool` and `jarsigner` tools now support the ECC algorithm in keypair generation and jar signing.
>
> RFE: [6870812](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6870812)

I'm using the 32-bit version 1.7.0_07, and I've tried keytool with -keyalg ECC, ECIES, ECDSA,... but I always get `Cannot derive signature algorithm`.

Am I using the wrong Java version? Am I using the wrong name for ECC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the [source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/jdk8-b132/src/share/classes/sun/security/tools/keytool/Main.java#l1556) for the algorithm selection. The allowed values are `DSA`, `RSA` and `EC`. These values are not documented anywhere as far as I can tell.

Comment: For future reference, here's the official documentation of the allowed values:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html

Answer (score 4):

I believe you have to install the unlimited strength policy for JCE to work with all algorithims. If you haven't done so already, it's at the bottom of this page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: Sorry, but I had already installed those (and tested by creating an RSA keystore), so there must be something else I'm missing.

Comment: OK, I found the problem, but it's a strange one. When I do "java -version", I get java version "1.7.0_07", but apparently, when I use keytool, I'm using the keytool from a different JDK on my machine. I found out by changing "keytool" into "./keytool.exe". Strange... The correct command is: keytool -genkeypair -keyalg EC -keysize 160 -keystore .keystore

Comment: In general ECC is safe to use with smaller key sizes, but 160 bit is pushing it. I'd rather go for 256, ECC is fast enough anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I needed the keystore only for testing purposes, but you're right. Even in a test environment, there's no reason not to use a key size of 256.