# create an ecdsa key

Tags: java, security, encryption, key, keytool

Is it possible to create an ECDSA key using the jdk 1.6 keytool?

I have tried with the `-genkey` command, but it doesn't seem to be supported.

Any ideas of how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK Java 6 has some limited support ECDSA regarding to TLS however it does not include any ECDSA implementation - it can make use of a third party JCE like BouncyCastle. It may be possible to use keytool with BouncyCastle to generate ECDSA keys but I have never tried that.

I would suggest to update to Java 7. But even using Java 7 there seems to be some problems in the early versions. According to the bug entry [6870812 : enhance security tools to use ECC algorithms](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6870812) you have to use 1.7.0_07 or higher for ECC support.

Furthermore a related question here on Stackoverflow [Java 7 keytool Elliptic Curve Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303079/java-7-keytool-elliptic-curve-encryption) points out that you have to install the unlimited strength policy files for JCE to make use of ECC.